# Extract specific html tag using python

Tags: python, html, pandas, list, beautifulsoup

In this link https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2012061469A3/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry I want the code to print the patent citations which should give publication number, title.

I then want to use pandas to put publication number in a column and the title in another column. so far I have used beautiful soup to convert the HTML file into a readable format. I have selected backward references HTML tag and under that I want it to print the publication number and title of the citations. I am citing one single example, but I have a folder full of HTML files which I will do later.

```py
x = soup.select('tr[itemprop="backwardReferences"]')
y = soup.select('td[itemprop="title"]')  # this line gives all the titles in the document not particularly under the patent citations
print(y)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following css selector combination. `select_one` ensures it matches the first table. If you worry about table order changing, you can add `:not` to exclude the other table, based on the text for the second (`Non-Patent Citations`table) with:

```
pd.read_html(str(soup.select('section:has(h2:contains("Patent Citations"):not(:contains("Non-Patent Citations"))) > table')))
```

Note:

1. That whilst the webpage, when rendered, visually displays 2 results for Patent Citations, there is only 1 located in this table in page-source, and therefore in `requests` content.
2. I have used pandas, as you stated you will use this import anyway, to generate the tabular output and subset specific columns.
3. You can use `pd.concat()` to combine dataframe in a loop over multiple files to generate a final, single, df.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
 
r = requests.get('https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2012061469A3/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('section:has(h2:contains("Patent Citations")) > table')))[0]
print(df.loc[: , ['Publication number', 'Title']])
```

Comment: Yes it works. Can you explain what it means when you write table?  I understand you select header h2 from HTML tags. And then what us >table mean? Why does the code not pick the second citations which I see on the URL link

Comment: f I check this link for example:patents.google.com/patent/US4458945?oq=US4458945A I think the HTML tags are different. I just can't get it to print the correct patent citations(16- the family to family citations don't get printed). I tried section:has(tr:contains("backwardReferences"))>table and it doesn't work. How do I use the tag tr itemprop=backwardReferences"  I think that may give all the citations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270690/extract-information-from-html-tags-into-pandas

Comment: The > table means table is a direct child of whatever is on left of >. If the returned html from requests, there is only 1 citation in the table rather than two. I assume js running on the webpage alters how this looks when viewing the page on the website. This doesn't run when using requests.

Comment: Your question asked for `patent citations` so I only returned those. Are you now saying you want all citations?

Comment: Yes I want all the citations to be listed. The first link I gave was an example perhaps of a simple case. I gave a second link as an example and perhaps the HTML tags under the backwardReferencesOrig are more accurate. I want this code to work for a whole folder full of HTML files. I want everything from the backwardReferences to be listed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270690/extract-information-from-html-tags-into-pandas