# Extract information from html tags into pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, string, beautifulsoup

I have a folder full of html files. I am trying to pick the right html tags so I print the citations correctly and the output I require is just the publication number and title. So far I did this with help from various posts in SO

```
with open(filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:# start loop to read HTML files in folder
    patent = f.read()
    #print(filename)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(patent, 'html.parser') 
    x=soup.select('tr[itemprop="backwardReferencesOrig"]')
    backorigdf= pd.read_html(str(x))
    print(backorigdf.loc[: , ['Publication number', 'Title']
```

But I get an error message ValueError: No tables found. I want the output of the multiple HTML files citations in a pandas dataframe format so it is easier for me to analyse data. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? this is the link to the HTML file https://patents.google.com/patent/US4458945?oq=US4458945A. This file is saved a HTML file on my computer and I don't want to read from the URL. I want to code to pick up from the HTML documents.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know the total number of results expected. In the following I retrieve 25 unique results by using :contains to target the citations h2 elements and then moving to the adjacent table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
 
r = requests.get('https://patents.google.com/patent/US4458945?oq=US4458945A')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_html(str(t.find_next('table')))[0]
                for t in soup.select('h2:contains("Citations", "Family Cites")')])

df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by=['Priority date'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
print(df)
```

Comment: This method is almost close. Thanks a lot ,however it picks the family citations by cited by as well. I need only up to patent citations (16). I need the output only for the 16 patent citations as displayed on the website.

Comment: can i use 'tr contains ("backwardReferences")). If you look at the original HTML source code all the citations are labelled under backwardReferences. view-source:patents.google.com/patent/US4458945?oq=US4458945A under the source code line 7473-7569 can i use soup.select backwardReferences

Comment: perfect i am very grateful to you!

Comment: When  I ran it through another folder full of HTML files  I get this error 
ValueError: No objects to concatenate. But  I certainly know there are files that have citations

Comment: likely because html structure varies across files. Impossible to say without seeing all the files. You will need to look for what is common across the files.

Comment: the only thing i find common is rt itemprop=backwardReferences.in the HTML source code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.read_html()` function for that:

```
url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US4458945?oq=US4458945A'
tables = pd.read_html(url, match='Publication number') #select table with match string
print(len(tables))

7 #It found 7 tables
```

You can display tables like:

```
display(tables[0])

#OR

for i in tables : 
    display(i)
```

One sample table from the result set:

```
    Publication number  Priority date   Publication date    Assignee    Title
0   US1722679A (en) *   1927-05-11  1929-07-30  Standard Oil Dev Co Pressure method of working oil sands
1   US1884859A (en) *   1930-02-12  1932-10-25  Standard Oil Dev Co Method of and apparatus for installing mine wells
2   US2193219A (en) *   1938-01-04  1940-03-12  Bowie   Drilling wells through heaving or sloughing fo...
3   US2989294A (en) *   1956-05-10  1961-06-20  Alfred M Coker  Method and apparatus for developing oil fields...
4   US4165903A (en) *   1978-02-06  1979-08-28  Cobbs James H   Mine enhanced hydrocarbon recovery technique
```

Note: You can be more specific on `match` parameter for what you are looking for. If you don't add match parameter It'will bring all tables from the page.

Results from table 2 and 3:

```
try: 
    tables = pd.read_html('page.html', match='Publication number')
    result_df = pd.concat([tables[2],tables[3]],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    display(result_df)
except:
    print('No tables Found')

    Publication number  Priority date   Publication date    Assignee    Title
0   US1722679A (en) *   1927-05-11  1929-07-30  Standard Oil Dev Co Pressure method of working oil sands
1   US1884859A (en) *   1930-02-12  1932-10-25  Standard Oil Dev Co Method of and apparatus for installing mine wells
2   US2193219A (en) *   1938-01-04  1940-03-12  Bowie   Drilling wells through heaving or sloughing fo...
3   US2989294A (en) *   1956-05-10  1961-06-20  Alfred M Coker  Method and apparatus for developing oil fields...
4   US4165903A (en) *   1978-02-06  1979-08-28  Cobbs James H   Mine enhanced hydrocarbon recovery technique
5   US1884858A (en) *   1929-03-22  1932-10-25  Standard Oil Dev Co Apparatus for simultaneously controlling oil m...
6   US1852717A (en) *   1930-09-08  1932-04-05  Union Oil Co    Gas lift appliance for oil wells
7   US1910762A (en) *   1932-03-08  1933-05-23  Union Oil Co    Gas lift apparatus
8   US2148327A (en) *   1937-12-14  1939-02-21  Gray Tool Co    Oil well completion apparatus
9   US3207221A (en) *   1963-03-21  1965-09-21  Brown Oil Tools Automatic blow-out preventor means
10  US3227229A (en) *   1963-08-28  1966-01-04  Richfield Oil Corp  Bit guide
11  US3613806A (en) *   1970-03-27  1971-10-19  Shell Oil Co    Drilling mud system
12  US3884261A (en) *   1973-11-26  1975-05-20  Frank Clynch    Remotely activated valve
13  US4046191A (en) *   1975-07-07  1977-09-06  Exxon Production Research Company   Subsea hydraulic choke
14  US4106562A (en) *   1977-05-16  1978-08-15  Union Oil Company Of California Wellhead apparatus
15  US4224988A (en) *   1978-07-03  1980-09-30  A. C. Co.   Device for and method of sensing conditions in...
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But i have files saved as HTML files in my computer. Not an URL.  Will this work for that? Again there should be 16 citations not 5. There Family cites family. That is why I wanted to use the backwardReferences tag because it can pick both.

Comment: Yes it works with local file as well like: ```tables = pd.read_html('path_to_the_local_.html ', match='Publication number')``` If you notice it founds 7 different table I just show one example most probably the result is one of the seven.  You can be more specific on match string to find exact table.

Comment: Is there anyway I can just select the citations and print only those tables. In different HTML file the table can be placed anywhere. However I require the table under the heading citations. Also I used beautiful soup to parse the HTML file. How can I proceed from that step? I want it to pick the tag backwardReferencesOrig and then print the table containing just the heading title and publication under citations.

Comment: You mean under Patent Citations ?

Comment: yes! There are some patents that have no citations at all. So when I run the code through the folder using this method it doesn't work. It says no tables found. Though in the same folder some do have citations. So I wanted the code to pick the beautiful soup tag <tr backwardReferences> and then under that pick all the values for title and publication number

Comment: i print x from my code I get something like this ``` [<tr itemprop="backwardReferencesFamily" itemscope="" repeat="">
<td>
<a href="/patent/US1884858A/en">
<span itemprop="publicationNumber">US1884858A</span>
              (<span itemprop="primaryLanguage">en</span>)
            </a>
<span itemprop="examinerCited">*</span>
</td>
<td itemprop="priorityDate">1929-03-22</td>
<td itemprop="publicationDate">1932-10-25</td>
<td><span itemprop="assigneeOriginal">Standard Oil Dev Co</span></td>
<td itemprop="title">Apparatus for simultaneously controlling oil mine wells 
     </td>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a try except?  I edited the solution please try last part

Comment: for some reason the try except didnt work. But without that it worked fine. I tried for another folder and I got the result as 
IndexError: list index out of range. For yet another folder I got ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Publication number'... Can you tell me for the above beautiful soup text message I got with all the HTML tags how do I select only the tite publication number under the header <tr itemprop="backwardReferencesFamily" itemscope="" repeat="">

Comment: view-source:https://patents.google.com/patent/US4458945?oq=US4458945A under the source code line 7473-7569 can i use soup.select backwardReferences and then how can i ask it to read the publication number and title from that?